# 3-key combination in Windows 10 on-screen keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, on-screen-keyboard

Do you guys know how to make a 3-key combination in Windows 10 on-screen keyboard? For example: Ctrl+Shift+T to reopen a closed tab.

Comment: With your fingers?

Comment: I obviously mean with a mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be as straight forward as clicking Ctrl, then Shift, then T, making sure that you gave Chrome the foreground.

[image]

Comment: It seems like you made a good point there with you gif... the on-screen keyboard must be in his full layout mode to achieve this!